# Is the update-kubeconfig command a client-only command or does it affect the cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I get the following warning/message when I run some k8s related commands

> Kubeconfig user entry is using deprecated API version client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1. Run 'aws eks update-kubeconfig' to update

and then I know I should run the command like so:

`aws eks update-kubeconfig --name cluster_name --dry-run`

I think the potential change will be client-side only and will not cause any change on the server side - the actual cluster. I just wanted some verification of this, or otherwise. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `update-kubeconfig` does not make any changes to the cluster. It will only update your local `.kube/config` file with the cluster info. Note that with the `--dry-run` flag, no change will be made at all - the resulting configuration will just be printed to `stdout`.